# power of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I  am trying to solve this complex number problem: If $(a + ib)^{11} = p + iq$, then prove that $b + ia = -q - ip$.  Tried to use De Moivre's theorem but got stuck up. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You must have a typo. I think you mean $(b+ia)^{11}$, not $b+ia$.

Comment: You also probably meant $-(q-ip)$...

Comment: $a,b$ are real numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Note that if $a+ib=\rho e^{i\theta}$, than $b+ia=\rho e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)}$

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be false if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $z_1 = a + ib, z_2=p + iq$ such that $z_1^{11}=z_2 \tag1$ Now suppose $b + ia = -q - ip$, from here we get $|z_1| =|z_2|$ and using (1) it follows $|z_1| =|z_2|=0$ or $|z_1| =|z_2|=1$. To contradict this let $z_1 = 1 + i$ and $z_2=z_1^{11}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use complex conjugate property $\overline{(zw)}=\overline{z}\cdot\overline{w}$ and fact that $b+ia=-i\overline{(a+ib)}$.
Note: Assuming you meant $(b+ia)^{11}=-(q-ip)$, otherwise your statement does not seem to hold...

Comment: I agree that there is a mistake in question. Trying to find out which is the right question.